# Is there any way to split "Send Code" and "Verify Code" to separate Steps?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am currently trying to split the process of "sending" the verification code and "verifying" the code into two different orchestration steps in my custom policy.

I was not able to figure out how to do so, currently I am not even sure, whether this is possible currently or not. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thats the standard way to sending and verifying the verification code.

[image]

[image]

I aim to have both steps separated. One page for sending the mail and one for typing in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, AZure AD B2C OTP features or controls do not allow the experience to be split into 2 or more orchestration steps. You can however create a couple of self asserted technical profiles that provided the required UX, one that connects to a custom REST API that generates/sends the OTP to the user, and  a second one that validates the input OTP against the very same REST API.

Design varies depending on your specific needs. Take a look to the following documentation for basic building blocks:

- [Define a self-asserted technical profile in an Azure Active Directory B2C custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile)
- [Define a validation technical profile in an Azure Active Directory B2C custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/validation-technical-profile)
- [Define a RESTful technical profile in an Azure Active Directory B2C custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile)